# Return first word in sentence?

Tags: python, string

Heres the question I have to answer for school

For the purposes of this question, we will define a word as ending a sentence if that word is immediately followed by a period. For example, in the text “This is a sentence. The last sentence had four words.”, the ending words are ‘sentence’ and ‘words’. In a similar fashion, we will define the starting word of a sentence as any word that is preceded by the end of a sentence. The starting words from the previous example text would be “The”. You do not need to consider the first word of the text as a starting word. Write a program that has:

An endwords function that takes a single string argument. This functioin must return a list of all sentence ending words that appear in the given string. There should be no duplicate entries in the returned list and the periods should not be included in the ending words.

The code I have so far is:

```
def startwords(astring):
    mylist = astring.split()
    if mylist.endswith('.') == True:
        return my list
```

but I don't know if I'm using the right approach. I need some help

Answer (score 3):

Several issues with your code. The following would be a simple approach. Create a list of bigrams and pick the second token of each bigram where the first token ends with a period:

```
def startwords(astring):
    mylist = astring.split()  # a list! Has no 'endswith' method
    bigrams = zip(mylist, mylist[1:])
    return [b[1] for b in bigrams if b[0].endswith('.')]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehenion](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are two things worth reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = astring.split()
if mylist.endswith('.')
```

that cannot work, one of the reasons being that `mylist` is a `list`, and doesn't have `endswith` as a method.

Another answer fixed your approach so let me propose a regular expression solution:

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"\.\s*(\w+)","This is a sentence. The last sentence had four words."))
```

match all words following a dot and optional spaces

result: `['The']`

Comment: A `[0]` at the end would make it more useful, as it returns the string in its own (`'The'`). `print(re.findall(r"\.\s*(\w+)", input)[0])`

Comment: @IvánC. yes, my answer finds all the words starting a sentence (the other correct answer does the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
def endwords(astring):
    mylist = astring.split('.')
    temp_words = [x.rpartition(" ")[-1] for x in mylist if len(x) > 1]
    return list(set(temp_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it ->

```
#!/bin/env/ python

from sets import Set

sentence = 'This is a sentence. The last sentence had four words.'
uniq_end_words = Set()

for word in sentence.split():
    if '.' in word:
        # check if period (.) is at the end
        if '.' == word[len(word) -1]:
            uniq_end_words.add(word.rstrip('.'))

print list(uniq_end_words)
```

Output (list of all the end words in a given sentence) ->

```
['words', 'sentence']
```

If your input string has a period in one of its word (lets say the last word),  something like this ->
*'I like the documentation of numpy.random.rand.'*

The output would be -  `['numpy.random.rand']`

And for input string *'I like the documentation of numpy.random.rand a lot.'*

The output would be -  `['lot']`

Answer (score 0):

This creates a set so there are no duplicates. Then goes on a for loop in a list of sentences (split by ".") then for each sentence, splits it in words then using [:-1] makes a list of the last word only and gets [0] item in that list.

```
print (set([ x.split()[:-1][0] for x in s.split(".") if len(x.split())>0]))
```

The if in theory is not needed but i couldn't make it work without it.

This works as well:

```
 print (set([ x.split() [len(x.split())-1] for x in s.split(".") if len(x.split())>0]))
```